# What is Big-Omega notation of $\log(n!)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I know that $\log(n!)$ is $O(n\log(n))$ since $n! < n^n$, but what is a lower bound for this function?

Comment: It is simply O(n log n)

Comment: Use [Stirling's lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for the factorial.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\log(n!) &= \log(n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2) \cdot ... \cdot (n/2) \cdot (n/2 - 1) \cdot (n/2 - 2) \cdot ... \cdot 2 \cdot 1) \\\\
& \ge \log(n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2) \cdot ... \cdot (n/2)) \\\\
& \ge \log(n/2 \cdot (n/2) \cdot (n/2) \cdot ... \cdot (n/2)) \\\\
& = \log( (n/2)^{n/2} ) \\\\
& = (n/2) \cdot \log (n/2) \\\\
& \ge cn\log(n) \text{ } \text{for some constant $c$}
\end{align}